# SQL Server 2014 Failure to access the DBMS server 08S01

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, esri-geodatabase

After upgrading our esri sde database from SQL Server 2008 to 2014 I am experiencing issues when overwriting some of our larger datasets. After some amount of time the overwriting process abruptly terminates. The error seems to be coming from the SQL side and reads: "Failure to access the DBMS server [08S01:[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]TCP Provider: The specified network name is no longer available.]"

This happens both when using python or the Arc tools user interface to perform either the Append or FeatureClassToFeatureClass tools. I've also tried running these tasks on off hours when the server is under minimal load to no avail. There were no issues when we were on SQL Server 2008 and the python scripts are the exact same as before the upgrade.

I have the SQL Server Native Client 2012 installed and the Remote Query Timeout setting is at 600 seconds. Our ArcGIS client is 10.3

Has anyone experienced and resolved this issue before?

Comment: The [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/databases/database-requirements-sqlserver.htm) states the required client library for SQL Server 2014.  Please edit your question to specify the release of the ArcGIS Client (2014 support wasn't added until 10.3)

Comment: Client is 10.3 This [doc](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/get-started/system-requirements/database-requirements-sqlserver.htm) seems to support that.  However the geodatabase versions have only been upgraded to 10.1 or 10.2.2. Either way this seems more of a network issue than anything else?